# why validation fails if using custom component inside a datatable?

Tags: validation, jsf, icefaces

I have a very strange problem.

The required validation **inside a datatable** works great if I am working directly with the original components for instance:

```
<ice:inputText id="inputTextt" field="#{bean[fieldValue]}" required="true"/>
<ice:message for="inputTextt"></ice:message>
```

will raise the required message when I press the button to POST the form.

Well, I have a custom component **gra:inputTextValidated** where I put the same stuff but a little bit more complex:

```
<ice:inputText
        id="#{id}"
        value="#{bean[field]}"
        rendered="#{rendered and empty validatorBean}"
        styleClass="#{styleClass} #{not required ? 'graNotRequired':''}"
        style="width: #{width};height:#{height}"
        partialSubmit="#{partialSubmit}"
        disabled="#{disabled}"
        required="#{required}">
    </ice:inputText>
    <ice:message
        styleClass="graValidationMessage graNotRequired"
        for="#{id}" />
```

so now, from the datatable I am calling my component like:

```
 <gra:inputTextValidated
                        id="inputText"
                        bean="#{bean}"
                        field="#{fieldValue}"
                        renderLabel="false"
                        required="true"
                        disabled="#{disabled}"
                        width="90%"
                        height="#{secondTabComponentsHeight}"
                        >
                    </gra:inputTextValidated>
```

Now *the validation message no longer occurs*. The gra:inputTextValidated component works fine, the value is rendered so it's only a problem about validation.

I've spent about 3 hours on this and **I am extremely sure it's something about the ids**, somehow the for attribute of the ice:message does not correctly see my input text from the custom component (but it is there, rendered as a spam).

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

The above code is working.